# Is there a way to combine the data of two rows with some intersecting data in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Good morning! I am currently working on creating a postgreSQL database with some client information, however I ran into an issue which I wasn't able to solve with my basic knowledge of SQL. Searching for this method also returned with no results which I found useful or applicable.

I have two tables: 'mskMobile' and 'emailData'. Both of those tables contain a column named 'email' and some of those emails overlap. I figured out that I can view those intersecting emails by requesting

```
SELECT "mailData".email
  FROM "mailData"
  JOIN "mskMobile"
  ON "mailData".email="mskMobile".email;
```

Now I want to write the data of two other columns of those common rows in 'mskMobile' named 'name' and 'surname' to the corresponding columns in 'emailData' (named identically), however I cannot find any answer on how to do so. Any suggestions on how to execute this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE "mksMobile" SET name = "mailData".name, surname = "mailData".surname
FROM "mailData"
WHERE "mailData".email = "mskMobile".email;
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research I came up with a following way of declaring it:

```
SELECT "mailData".email, "mskMobile".num, "mskMobile".name
  FROM "mailData"
  INNER JOIN "mskMobile"
  ON "mailData".email="mskMobile".email;
```

This allowed me to build a new table with the data combined.